# Scala SBT how to run both test and it test at the same time

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-collections, scalatest, scalaz

For my project I have the test and it tests in my sbt build. To run the tests I type sbt test and then it:test. Is there a way in the build.sbt to combine both test and it:test so all my tests are executed in one command?

Comment: If you don't want them separate, why are they separate in the first place?

Comment: They rely on different dependencies and would not work if in the same project

Answer (score 6):

You can add an alias:

```
addCommandAlias("testAll", "; test ; it:test")
```

Comment: Is it possible to have test and it:test both run under just test?

Answer (score 4):

You can override `test` to run both `test` and `it:test`:

```scala
test := {
  test.in(Test).value
  test.in(IntegrationTest).value
}
```

Comment: Hey, this works, what would I need to do if I wanted to override it:test? Also it seems like if a test fails it only shows a TestFailedException instead of which test failed

Comment: `it:test` is the `test` task scoped to `IntegrationTest`. To override it, try `test.in(IntegrationTest) := {stuff}`. I'm not sure why your tests aren't giving you enough output; that might be a different setting.